# CLion local Debug: can't find epoll_wait.c

Tags: debugging, clion

I was debugging a program in my local machine by attaching the process in Clion. But I get this in GDB console:

```
Thread 1 "envoy-static" received signal SIGSTOP, Stopped (signal).
0x000055bab6adfa9f in std::atomic<absl::OnDeadlockCycle>::load (this=0x55bab704f570 <absl::(anonymous namespace)::synch_deadlock_detection>, __m=std::memory_order_acquire) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/atomic:254
254 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/atomic: No such file or directory.

Thread 24 "wrk:worker_9" received signal SIGSTOP, Stopped (signal).
[Switching to Thread 0x7f942ede9640 (LWP 10252)]
0x00007f9439f25fde in epoll_wait (epfd=48, events=0x790bf206480, maxevents=32, timeout=100) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c:30
30  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c: No such file or directory.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f9435df7640 (LWP 10238)]
```

Secondly, CLion can't find some frames. For example:
[image: The current frame's file std_function.h is not found or ...]